# Intersection observer not observing specific divs/sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Basically my intersection observer works fine on all the elements I set him to watch apart from this section. **Please help**

```
<section class="introduction-section mb-5 watch">
```

```js
// elements
let elements_to_watch = document.querySelectorAll('.watch');
// callback 
let callback = (items) => {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.target.id);
    if (item.isIntersecting) {
      console.log("... now in");
      item.target.classList.add("in-page");
    } else {
      console.log("... now out");

      item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

    }
  });
}
// observer
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 0.57
});
// apply
elements_to_watch.forEach((element) => {
  observer.observe(element);
});
```

```css
.introduction-section {
  background-color: var(--clr-dark);
  align-items: center;
}
.introduction-title-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.introduction-section .title {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: calc(var(--fs-h2) * 1.2);
  color: var(--clr-light);
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 30rem;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(25% -20rem);
  position: fixed;

  transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.introduction-title-container.in-page .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section class="introduction-section mb-5 watch" id=section>
  <div class="row wrapper h-100 " id=wrapper>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction1>
      <h2 class="title">
        A SmartWatch is born that goes beyond all limits.
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction2>
      <h2 class="title">For Athletes who challenge the impossible.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction3>
      <h2 class="title">The call to the Adventure begins.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

It should change the class "watch" to "in-page" but for some reason on this section it won't do it.

As I said the watch class gets changed on the col-12 divs but not on the section, and neither the row because I tried it.

I have console logged the elements_to_watch nodelist in JS and the section was there so I don't understand why it doesnt work...

Comment: I changed your code to a snippet and added a couple of debug messages. The code seems to be working fine as far as I can tell. You say in the question that the code should *change* the "watch" class to "in-page", but it makes no attempt to do that (and I don't think it should). What it does is add or remove "in-page". If you look at the console messages, it is doing just that.

Comment: could it be bootstrap's `h-100` class? it sets the height of the row to 100%, not sure if that conflicts

Comment: @GrafiCode that's a possibility I guess; the snippet does not involve any Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: btw to test the behavior I was squeezing the whole browser window up and down, crude but effective.

Comment: @Pointy for some reason on the code snippet works fine but on my side it doesn't only for that specific section, I'm even more confused now

Comment: @JIRACHI well there could be something about your CSS or the surrounding structure of your DOM that makes the visibility calculation different. You might want to try logging what the "intersectionRatio" value is for the element that is not apparently working.

Comment: @Pointy Ok so I checked better in the new code snipped and the section itself loses the class immidiately, it goes straight to "section ...now out"

Comment: Well it goes to "out" when the callback is initially called when the observer is set up.  But that certainly is different behavior.

Comment: Answer added. The issue is with how your CSS makes the size of the `<section>` much larger, so 57% of it may not fit in a small viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see the problem now with the added CSS. I don't fully understand why, but with the fancy CSS for the "introduction" elements, the container (the `<section>` is MUCH bigger. Thus, getting 57% of it into the viewport takes a much larger viewport.

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you can see what I'm talking about if you take the "watch" class off of the `<section>`, and then make a new `IntersectionObserver` with a smaller threshold (like 0.20 maybe), and observe the section (using the same callback) with that observer.

So, with the "watch" removed from the `<section>`, the JavaScript would be:

```
// observer for each heading
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 0.57
});
// apply
elements_to_watch.forEach((element) => {
  observer.observe(element);
});
// observer for section container
observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 0.20
});
observer.observe(document.getElementById("section"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, now I understand: that section is actually so much larger because it's the container of 3 divs with 100 vh height. So 57% treshold mend that I need to scroll over 2 full viewports before it gets the in-page class

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you want to achieve.
As you are saying, you want to remove the `.watch` class every time your `Intersection observer` is passing throught the specific sections of your page. I tested the code by removing the `.watch` and adding the `.in-page` and viceversa.

Open your Google Chrome Elements and observe the DOM changing,
while you navigate in and out of the specified sections.
You will notice that there is a change of classes in the specific sections that possess the `.watch` class.

The row section won't change because you are not really applying the class `.watch` to it.
You are only selecting DOM elements which have the class watch.
I added the class to every one of the elements and it is working properly. I hope that can give you a hint.

```js
// elements
let elements_to_watch = document.querySelectorAll('.watch');
// callback 
let callback = (items) => {
  console.log(items[0].target.id);
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.isIntersecting) {
      console.log("... now in");
      item.target.classList.remove("watch");
      item.target.classList.add("in-page");
    } else {
      console.log("... now out");
      item.target.classList.add("watch");
      item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

    }
  });
}
// observer
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 0.57
});
// apply
elements_to_watch.forEach((element) => {
  observer.observe(element);
});
```

```html
<section class="introduction-section mb-5 watch" id=section>
  <div class="row wrapper h-100 watch" id=wrapper>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction1>
      <h2 class="title watch">
        A SmartWatch is born that goes beyond all limits.
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction2>
      <h2 class="title watch">For Athletes who challenge the impossible.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 px-0 introduction-title-container watch" id=introduction3>
      <h2 class="title watch">The call to the Adventure begins.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried it and on my side, even on opera and firefox (I usually use chrome) and every section gets added the class '"in-page", but that specific section still doesnt't get it apllided to it. Also the important part is that the elements get the class in-page, not necessarely deleting the class watch

Comment: This is correct, but the code already worked, and as far one can see from the  code all the "watch" class does is identify the elements to be watched. If it doesn't do anything after the observing is initialized, removing and adding "watch" is sort-of pointless.

Comment: @Pointy ok so now I added the css in the code snippet and as you can see even if the section itself is in the viewport, it doesn't get the class "in-page" which I need to create a different effect

Comment: But it definitely **does** get the class "in-page", you can clearly see it with the browser inspector. What exactly do you expect "in-page" to do?

Comment: I don't see your CSS in the snippet; when you add it, you have to "Save into post" and then save the edit

Comment: @Pointy I added the css in my original snippet, the one in my question, I refreshed the page and I can see it so I think it's there. 
Anyway, yes, I expect the "in-page" class to be added to the section but it doesn't work on my side and even on the snippet I modified as I said... (With the browser inspector it's not there)